# Proving relations between (sub-)rings and a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R \neq 0$ be a commutative ring, $G$ be a finite group, $\#G >
>  2$.
>
> 1) $H$ subgroup of G $\Rightarrow$ monoid ring R[H] is a subring of
>   monoid ring R[G]
>
> 2) Let $x := \sum_{g\in G}g, \ X := \left\{ r x + r'e_G \mid r,r' \in
>  R \right\} \Rightarrow$ $X$ subring of $R[G]$ and there is no subgroup
>    H of G, so that $X = R[H]$.

1)

As far as I understand, I can follow associativity for both operations from $H \leq G$, and do only need to show that the operations are closed, am I right?

Let $x,y \in R[H] \Leftrightarrow x = \sum_{h\in H}a_h h, y = \sum_{h\in H}b_h h$.

$$x + y = \sum_{h \in H} (\underbrace{a_h + b_h}_{\in H}) h \in R[H]$$

$$x y = \sum_{h\in H}\left(\sum_{h_1,h_2 \in H, h_1h_2=h} \underbrace{a_{h_1} b_{h_2}}_{\in H} \right)h \in R[H]$$

Is this all that need to be shown here? Maybe it is left to show that the sums are finite, but that should directly follow from the fact, that the sums of x and y are finite, am I right?

2)

How do I show that there is no such subgroup? I played around with the definitions but didn't find an approach, can you please help me to find a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding 1)

Usually the subring test involves closure of multiplication and subtraction (but this isn't too different from addition here). Also $a_h+b_h$ is an element of the ring $R$, not of the group $H$, so your notation is a bit confusing. The point is that a general element of $R[H]$ is a formal sum of elements of $H$ with arbitrary coefficients in $R$ and after multiplication or subtraction of two elements of $R[H]$ the result is again a formal sum which only involves elements of $H$.

Regarding 2)

You can think of the set $X$ as vectors $(a,b,b,\dots)$ with $a,b \in R$. All group elements have the same coefficient, except the identity element, which can be anything. Now for any subgroup $H$ $R[H]$ contains the element $(0,1,0,\dots)$. Can this element be in $X$ if $\#G>2$?

Comment: thank you for your answer. So my 1) is correct if I show that $x-y$ is in $R[H]$, right? By the way, why does this suffice in order to prove $R[H]$ is a subring? 2) Sorry, but I don't understand your approach. Why can be X considered as the set of vectors $(a,b,b,\cdots,b)$? And how do you generate $(0,1,0,\cdots)$ this way?

Comment: If a subset $S$ is closed under multiplication and subtraction, then $a-a=0 \in S$ and then $0-a=-a \in S$. Then $a-(-b)=a+b \in S$. So $S$ is closed under addition, multiplication, it contains $0$ and additive inverses. The rest (associativity of addition and multiplication, commutativity of addition and distributivity) follows from the fact that it is a subset.

Comment: You can view every formal sum as a vector where the position stands for the group element and the entry in the position stands for the coefficient. This is because $R[G]$ is a module. This viewpoint is not necessary, but very convenient. $X$ is the set $a e_g+b \sum_{g\in G} g$. Then $X$ viewed as vectors have the form $(a+b,b,b,\dots)$. Since $R[H]$ is the set of all formal sums $\sum_{h\in H} a_h h$ it specifically contains the element $1 h$. for some $h$.

Comment: thank your for the answers! Ok, I understand that the vectors of X have the form $(a+b,b,b,\cdots)$. You take the element $1h \in R$. But what if I took the vector of X with $a = 1, b = 0$? Why won't that work?

Comment: You choose an element of $R[H]$ where all the coefficients are zero, except the one of a single $h$ (which isn't $e_G$, I should have mentioned that). Then you get $(0, 1, 0,\dots)$. (The first coordinate corresponds to $e_G$, the second to $h$ and the rest to the other elements of $G$). But no vector of $X$ can be in this form ($a=1,b=0$ is $(1, 0, 0,\dots)$ which isn't of this form). So $R[H]$ cannot be $X$. Also think about the case where the group only has $2$ elements.